# Saving Score from Form

Tags: android, textview

I want a score to be passed to the form where users will enter their name and the score should be printed on the `TextView` below the user name. On a click of the submit button, the score and user name should be displayed on score form.

Comment: SO is not a Code engine. Do your own homework

Comment: I'm really confused by your wording, what exactly do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).putExtra() to pass values through intents.
then you'll able to get values by using

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int score = intent.getIntExtra("score",0);
```

you can simply save values using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or if you are trying to save large quantity of values,.use [sqlitedatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html).

Comment: but i tried this way                                            Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),Form.class);
intent.putExtra("MY_SCORE", mSnakeView.str );
startActivity(intent); here str is the variable in which the score is saved in the game. will it do?

Comment: try this: Intent intent=new Intent(yourClassName.this,Form.class); 
intent.putExtra("MY_SCORE", str); 
startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Intent and Database. Using Intent you can pass value (Score) from one Activity to another and then save it to database. later where you want to show the score you can just access DB and show that.